# PHP mysql LEFT JOIN output

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have php-script running on top of apache. Every time when user goes to specific URL, he/she will get csv-file.

Column names are fetched like this (thanks to Daniel Figueroa :)

```
$csv_output .= "\n";
// get the column name from the first DB (ins.data)
mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die("Can not connect to DB1.");
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table." WHERE Field NOT IN
('ID','Key','Text')");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$csv_output .= $row['Field']."; ";
$i++;
}
}

// get the column names from the second DB (Cu.data)
mysql_select_db($db2, $link) or die("Can not connect to DB2.");
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table2." ");
 ;
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $csv_output .= $row['Field']."; ";
    $i++;
}
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
```

Actual query on PHP-script goes like this:

```
$values = mysql_query(" SELECT ins.data.`Date`,  ins.data.`Number`, 
 ins.data.`Email`, ins.data.`TargetId`, ins.data.`CSW`,
 ins.data.`TSW`, ins.data.`CType`,
 Cu.data.`Cus`, Cu.data.`Co`,Cu.data.`Ci`,
 Cu.data.`SID`, Cu.data.`SType` 
 FROM ins.data
 LEFT JOIN  Cu.data ON (ins.data.TargetId = Cu.data.TargetID)
 ORDER BY ins.data.ID DESC");
```

Output of 'desc':

```
mysql> desc ins.data;
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| ID                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| Date              | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| Number            | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| Text              | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| Email             | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| TargetId          | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| CSW               | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| TSW               | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| Key               | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| CType             | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc Cu.data;
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Title    | decimal(15,0) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Cu       | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Co       | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Ci       | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| SID      | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| TargetID | varchar(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| SType    | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| empty1   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| empty2   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| empty3   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| empty4   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| empty5   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| empty6   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| empty7   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

UPDATE 3:

This is no more NATURAL LEFT JOIN-issue. Replaced with LEFT JOIN.

Added fields empty1-5 to ins.data to get data to csv-file. Without fields empty1-5, only data from first db (ins.data) was on csv.file.

Now i have data on all fields but field (or column names on excel) names on csv are on wrong order and not wanted fields (columns) are visible like Title and empty1-5.

Any ideas how to fix this? Some other way to get Field names to csv-file without "SHOW COLUMNS"?

I could write with 'echo' in the beginning of csv-file values what i want. ie
"Date; Number; Email; TargetID, CSW; TSW; CType; Cu; SID; Co; Ci; SType;" but i am so newbie with PHP that i don't know how :(

Another issue is that if field ID is first column on excel, excel cannot handle that and it must be excluded from SHOW COLUMNS output.

UPDATE4: Added more empty-fields to DB2 (Cu.data) and reordered SQL-query, now all values are visible and on right order.

Comment: view the updated syntax example in my edit

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

First of all, your table naming schema is weird and unusual... but assuming I understand it correctly then this query should work (if it does not then rename your tables without the dots (periods) to make things less confusing:

```
mysql_query('SELECT ins.data.Date, ins.data.Number, ins.data.Email, ins.data.TID, ins.data.CSW, ins.data.TSW, ins.data.CType, CU.data.SID, cu.data.SType, cu.data.CU, cu.data.CO, cu.data.Ci, FROM ins.data, cu.data ORDER BY ins.data.ID DESC');
```

---

According to to the mysql_query function reference, data should not end with a semicolon when using mysql_query in PHP... i never put the semicolon in there so I don't ever have a problem, that's what I initially noticed with your script (as I said i've never tried it so I don't know if thats the issue). Should be:

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT Date, Number, Email, TID, CSW, TSW, CType, SID, SType, Cu, Co, Ci FROM ins.data NATURAL LEFT JOIN Cu.data ORDER BY ID DESC");
```

Also, when doing JOINS, usually you specify what column belongs to what table... like in the standard mysql example here:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
// Construct our join query
$query = "SELECT family.Position, food.Meal ".
 "FROM family LEFT JOIN food ".
    "ON family.Position = food.Position"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['Position']. " - ". $row['Meal'];
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

I don't always use the JOIN commands either... you can use an alternative syntax like so:

```
mysql_query('SELECT ... FROM t1, t2, t3 WHERE t1.b = t2.b AND t2.c = t3.c AND t1.a = t3.a');
```

Comment: Ok. Competence exceeded. t1/t2/t3 are tables but what is t1.b?

Comment: Lets say I have two tables... for instance 1 table is called 'users' and the other table is called 'comments'... if for instance, a user posted a comment and I wanted to retrieve it i could have syntax like so (it would be easier to give you a solution knowing your DB structure): mysql_query('SELECT users.username, comments.comment FROM users, comments WHERE users.user_id = comments.user_id'); --- in this example we have the shared id of user_id to compare table to table

Comment: Wow. Works almost perfectly. I mean this "SELECT ins.data.Date, etc." I have 979 rows on ins.data and cu.data has 1521 rows. Your query outputs about 1,44 million rows (SQL from command line). And my browser is still waiting csv :D

Comment: Users are inserting data to ins.data via WWW (currently 979 entries). php-script creates csv-file with 979 rows and fetches from Cu.data additinal info to the csv.

Comment: 979 * 1521 = 1489050 and thats what php-script is doing now.

Comment: Seems that problem is with NULL-values on my PHP-script

Comment: Humm, query founds data from ind.data which does not exist at all on Cu.data. This is OK but how to get PHP working so that it generates csv with data on all fields?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting aliases on table names. It will make the query more readable, too:

```
SELECT 
    i.`Date`, i.Number, i.Email, i.TID, i.CSW, i.TSW, i.CType, 
    c.Cu, c.Co, c.Ci, c.SID, c.TID, c.SType  
FROM 
    ins.data AS i
  LEFT JOIN 
    Cu.data AS c
      ON i.TID =  c.TID 
ORDER BY 
    i.ID DESC ;
```

Comment: Interesting, direct SQL via command line gives error: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ins.data.Date' in 'field list'. Querying only i.Date, i.Number, iEmail from i.data without any joins is ok. I haven't found any typos from my query.

Comment: Can you try with the edit (putting backticks around `Date`: `i.\`Date\``

Comment: Time to take some distance to this. Continuing troubleshooting maybe tomorrow. Thanks to Jeffery and ypercube for your help so far!

Comment: The problem lies in the PHP code probably. Not sure why you are complicating things (to find the names of the columns returned, using the `SHOW COLUMNS`).

Comment: This is so frustrating! My workaround; cron calls shell-script and email csv works ok but this damn PHP does not work!

Comment: After editing second SHOW COLUMNS to $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table2." " ); AND adding five empty fields to Cu.data i finally managed to get all info to csv.